# Self-hosted crowdsourced translation software

Tags: gratis, web-apps, collaboration, crowdsourcing, localization

I'm looking for a self-hosted collaborative translation software, preferably written in PHP.

I liked [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/) but it's not free for private projects and my budget is zero.

Please help me, I've already seen [Pootle](http://pootle.translatehouse.org/) (Python, seemed impossible to install) and [Weblate](http://weblate.org/) (Python, I don't want to be tied to Git).

Comment: While Weblate insists on storing the data in Git, you can export it from another version control system to it and then import it back. So you don't have to use Git otherwise.

Comment: BTW: Weblate currently supports Mercurial as well...